# How to animate view with velocity by DragGesture in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

**Topic**: I have `DragGesture` on my `View` and I want to change offset of the `View` by velocity value from `DragGesture`.

**Details**: I made custom sheet view and bind `DragGesture` to it. When user swipe down on the view it takes offset value from gesture `value.translation.height`. If swipe gesture is fast enough - view dissapear from screen by slide down animation.

**Problem**: Animation of disappearing has static speed value, but users swipe can be more faster or slower. As a result it looks like *obstacle* - view start moving with speed of drag gesture, but after gesture ended it change speed to value from animation.

**Code of custom sheet view**:

```swift
@State var offset = 0
@State var lastDragPosition: DragGesture.Value?

VStack {
  Text("Sheet")
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.offset(y: offset)
.gesture(
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged(onDragChanged(value:))
        .onEnded(onDragEnded(value:))
)
.ignoresSafeArea()
```

**On view drag changed**:

```swift
func onDragChanged(value: DragGesture.Value) {
    if value.translation.height > 0 {
        // Move view down by finger dragging
        offset = value.translation.height
    }

    // Save last position for calculating velocity of gesture
    lastDragPosition = value
}
```

**On view drag ended**:

```swift
func onDragEnded(value: DragGesture.Value) {
    let timeDiff = value.time.timeIntervalSince(lastDragPosition!.time)
    let speed: CGFloat = .init(
        value.translation.height - lastDragPosition!.translation.height
    ) / CGFloat(timeDiff)

    // If velocity of drag gesture high enough...
    if speed > 300 {
        // ...animate it to disappear
        withAnimation(.interactiveSpring(
            response: 0.27, // This value is hard coded!
            dampingFraction: 0.78,
            blendDuration: 0.25
        )) {
            offset = 800
        }

        return
    } else {
        // Else return view offset to initial state (top of the screen)
        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.28)) {
            offset = 0
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it is some kind of math issue. But maybe there is SwiftUI native solution?

Comment: Look at `Animation.speed(...` modifier

Comment: Have you discovered a solution for this? I am facing the Same problem and trying to find a solution…